# Any songs with the same music but different lyrics?

Tags: lyrics

[Dave Mustaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Mustaine) (former member of [Metallica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallica)) left the band and took the song *Mechanix* with him to his new band [Megadeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth). After that Metallica changed the lyrics and the name of the song and made it *Four Horsemen*.

Are there any other songs like this - music is the same but the lyrics are different?

Comment: would [lyrics in a different language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsSrGWp-ZFE) count? the music is the same, and the meaning of the words is the same, but the words don't quite sound the same

Comment: no i thought of taking the song and changing it

Comment: As you can see icey, there are a ton of songs that have this property (I'll add another which is _God save the Queen_ and _My Country, 'Tis of Thee_ not to mention pretty much every parody song ever) as it's a very effect way to arrange especially when people already know the song. Because of this I'm closing this question as too broad because there are way too many answers, but feel free to continue to this in [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/off-the-record).

Comment: Tons and tons. Listen to Pink Floyd's "The Wall":  'Another Brick in the Wall' pts 1,2,and 3 are the same; 'Vera Lynn' and 'Bring the Boys Back Home'; 'In the Flesh?' and 'In the Flesh'...  Pink Floyd love to recycle their own music.

Comment: Tom Waits included two very different songs with essentially the same melody on his *Alice* album (the title track, and "Poor Edward").  From the sublime to the ridiculous, Kid Rock included alternate versions of a single track on his latest album --a bawdy version with his own lyric on the explicit version, and a more sensitive version with a lyric by Bob Seger on the clean version of the album.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly in the same genre… but I think [Comme d'Habitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comme_d%27habitude) might be one of the most famous ones… even if you've never heard of the original.

You might know it better after the lyrics were re-written by [Paul Anka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Anka) & the song given to [Frank Sinatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Sinatra), with it's rather more famous new title of [My Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Way).

Answer (score 2):

ABC's and Twinkle, Twinkle Little Star

Comment: Ha!  I'm 48 and never noticed that before.  :)

Comment: and ba ba black sheep

Answer (score 1):

God Save The Queen and My Country Tis Of Thee
and of course National Anthem, re-written over a British drinking song

Answer (score 0):

Barney's theme song and This Old Man

Answer (score 0):

Ugly Day, and Rhubarb Pie, both by Five Iron Frenzy. I would provide links, but I'm at work and can't right now. Five Iron Frenzy was a 90's and 00's Christian Ska Band. Both songs have exactly the same music (I can guarantee it, but they might have even just re-record lyrics on the same inst. tracks)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this directly addresses your question, but there are some simple chord progressions that used by many different bands but typically with a different melody each time. Three of the most famous and common are:

- The Blues progression - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-bar_blues
- The 50's progression 1 6 4 5 -
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50s_progression
- The 1 5 6 4 progression - Here is an excellent comedic song parodying its overuse. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pidokakU4I